# How can I implement RBAC on API level?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, acl, rbac

Before you actually start thinking about the solution, let me explain the situation I am facing right now.

We are creating kind of an employee management portal, where an organisation can purchase the licence and can start using it.
So as a feature, admin of an organisation can create any number of roles consisting CRUD permission on modules. In simpler language, suppose you have modules from 1 to 10, then an admin can create say role1 and can choose any module from 1 to 10 each having separate CRUD permissions linked with them.

So the problem here is, how can I add role base access control on APIs.

Please also note that there are some shared apis as well across 2 or more different modules.

As an output a user should able to access apis through the authorised modules only. And can only perform set of operations like read, write, delete, update based on assigned permission.

Comment: You might use middleware to authorize user, and you might check this library [hakki](https://github.com/dashersw/hakki)

Comment: If I am not wrong, the problem with hakki and node_acl library is that they work on pre defined roles.  And in this case an user can create role by any name which can includes any allowed methods on any number of modules.